# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'type' and 'float'

Tags: python

I want to get input of cost.  Have cost divided by `.65` and output answer as list.

```
cost = int                                                                  
raw_input('What is the cost:  ')
print 'list = ',   cost  /.65
```

Have tried `int(cost)`--- `float(cost)`   `int('cost')` --`input` instead of `raw_input`

Any help would be appreciated.

Have been to many python tutorials but unable to understand solution.

Comment: Is this your code? What a dollar sign doing there?

Comment: The dollar sign comes up automatically since i downloaded vim-pathogen.  I don't know how to get it to stop and it does not seem to affect anything.

Comment: `it does not seem to affect anything` It affects the ability to understand ur code

Comment: Take it step by step. Google "reading input python", then "concatenating strings".

Comment: cost = int
    raw_input('What is the cost: ')
    print 'list = ', cost /.65

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you just assigned the type object `int`to variable `cost`. May be you were trying to assign a data type to variable `cost` like we do in C, but that is not required in python.

> cost = int

You asked for user input but didn't assign the returned value to any variable, so that value is actually lost.

> raw_input('What is the cost: ')

This will raise error as you're trying to divide a type object(`int`) by a float.

> print 'list = ', cost /.65

A simple solution:

```
#get input from user, the returned value will be saved in the variable cost.
cost = raw_input('What is the cost:  ')  

# convert cost to a float as raw_input returns a string, float 
# is going to be more appropriate for money related calculations than an integer
cost_fl = float(cost)  

#use string formatting 
print 'list = {}$'.format(cost_fl /.65)
```

Comment: Great answer (and beat me to a very similar answer). But one minor nitpick: `int` isn't actually a function, it's a type. (Also, I'll give you 2:1 odds that he really wants `float` here, not `int`, but just didn't know there was such a thing.)

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
while True:
    try:
        cost=float(raw_input('What is the cost: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Can't understand your input. Try again please." 
        continue

print 'list=${:.2f}'.format(cost/.65)
```

If you run this:

```
What is the cost: rr
Can't understand your input. Try again please.
What is the cost: 5.67
list=$8.72
```

With the `try` / `except` with input, this will filter out user input errors.

Comment: You don't need the `continue` after the `except` clause